# Subset dataset to 99.5th percentile for each of a categorical variable

Tags: r, subset, categorical-data, quantile

I want to subset a data.frame to keep only the 99.5th percentile of each of a categorical variable.

My data has minutes used = minutes
And location = location

I would like to take out the top .5 percent of minutes data for each location.

The new subset would have 99.5 percentile of location 1. 99.5 percentile of location 2, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would likely solve your problem although it'd be really helpful if you could post your data.

```
library(plyr)

#add a column with information on where the 99.5% cutoff is
new.dataset1 <- ddply(your.dataset, "location", mutate, minutes.99.5.cutoff =                         
                      quantile(minutes.used, 0.95)) 

#subset the data to only include the bottom 99.5% of the data, then only 
#select the first two columns
trimmed.dataset <- new.dataset1[which(new.dataset1$minutes.used <= 
                                      new.dataset1$minutes.99.5.cutoff),1:2]
```